# Não consigo fazer um vetor apontar corretamente para função que ele pertence

Tags: c, c++

Já tentei várias vezes, mas o compilador não entende as referências feitas no cabeçalho da função `void CalculaValorparaPagar(float ValorPago[MAX], float Quant_Kwh[MAX],float Preco[MAX], int bandeira[MAX], int tipo[MAX])` e na main `CalculaValorparaPagar(&ValorPago[MAX],Quant_Kwh,Preco,bandeira,tipo/i/);` e dá o seguinte erro:

> [Error] cannot convert 'float' to 'float' for argument '1' to 'void
>   CalculaValorparaPagar(float, float, float, int, int)

Como devo proceder?

```
                #include <stdio.h>
                //#include "headerfiledoconsumo.h"
                #define MAX 2
                int x;  
                float Imposto[MAX], Taxa_ilum [MAX];
                float Taxa_Band_Tar [MAX];
                float Quant_Kwh [MAX];
                int tipo [MAX];
                float ValorPago[MAX];
                float Preco[MAX];
                int bandeira[MAX];

                //void CalculaValorparaPagar();
                //void fazperguntas();
                //void imprimevalorpagar();

                void fazperguntas(/*float Quant_Kwh[MAX],float Preco[MAX],int tipo[MAX],int bandeira[MAX]*/){

                for (int i= 0; i<MAX; i++){

                //printf("Informe seu nome:\n");
                //scanf("%s", &nome[i]);
                printf("Informe seu consumo em KW: \n");
                scanf("%f", &Quant_Kwh[i]);
                getchar();
                printf("Digite o preco do Khw: \n");
                scanf("%f", &Preco[i]);
                getchar();
                printf("Informe o tipo de consumidor que voce eh: 1(residencial), 2(comercial), 3(Industrial)\n");
                scanf("%d", &tipo[i]);
                getchar();
                printf("Informe a bandeira tarifaria: Verde(1), Amarela(2), Vermelha(3)\n");
                scanf("%d", &bandeira[i]);
                getchar();

                }
                }



                void CalculaValorparaPagar(float *ValorPago[MAX], float Quant_Kwh[MAX],float Preco[MAX], int bandeira[MAX], int tipo[MAX]){


                    //int i = 10;

                    for(int i=0; i<MAX;i++){

                    if (bandeira[i] == 1){
                        Taxa_Band_Tar[i] = 0;
                    }

                    if(bandeira[i] == 2 || Quant_Kwh[i] > 100){

                        x = (Quant_Kwh[i]/100);
                        Taxa_Band_Tar[i] = x*3.5;
                    }

                    if(bandeira[i] == 3 || Quant_Kwh [i] >100){

                        x = (Quant_Kwh[i]/100);
                        Taxa_Band_Tar[i] = x*10.5;
                    }


                    if (tipo[i] == 1){

                        Taxa_ilum[i] = 23.45;
                    }

                    if(tipo[i] == 2){

                        Taxa_ilum[i] = 29.23;
                    }

                    if(tipo[i] == 3){

                        Taxa_ilum[i] = 37.06;
                    }



                    Imposto[i] = 0.04*Quant_Kwh[i] + 0.02*Taxa_ilum[i];
                    *ValorPago[i] = Quant_Kwh[i]*Preco[i] + Taxa_ilum[i] + Imposto[i] + Taxa_Band_Tar[i];

                    }
                }


                    void imprimevalorpagar(){

                        for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++){ 

                 printf("Consumidor %d  Valor a pagar: %f\n", i,ValorPago[i]); 
                }

                }






                int main() {



                fazperguntas();


                CalculaValorparaPagar(&ValorPago[MAX],Quant_Kwh,Preco,bandeira,tipo/*i*/);


                imprimevalorpagar();

                }
```

Comment: A primeira coisa que precisa decidir se vai colocar as variáveis como globais ou locais, fazer os dois ao mesmo tempo não dá certo. É mais complicado fazer tudo local, mas é o certo, global é gambiarra.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou tentar aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Eu já comentei o quanto odeio *printf* e *scanf*? Enfim, ignore.

A mensagem que o [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) exibe é bem mais esclarecedora:

> list.c:24:5: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
>
> ```
> scanf("%f", &Quant_Kwh[i]);
>
> ^~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> list.c:27:5: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
>
> ```
> scanf("%f", &Preco[i]);
>
> ^~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> list.c:30:5: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
>
> ```
> scanf("%d", &tipo[i]);
>
> ^~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> list.c:33:5: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute [-Wunused-result]
>
> ```
> scanf("%d", &bandeira[i]);
>
> ^~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> list.c:110:25: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'float *' to parameter of type 'float **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> CalculaValorparaPagar(&ValorPago[MAX],Quant_Kwh,Preco,bandeira,tipo/*i*/);
>
> ```
>                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> list.c:41:35: note: passing argument to parameter 'ValorPago' here
>
> void CalculaValorparaPagar(float *ValorPago[MAX], float Quant_Kwh[MAX],float Preco[MAX], int bandeira[MAX], int tipo[MAX]){
>                                     ^
>
> 5 warnings generated.

O compilador aponta que você tentou passar `float*` como se fosse `float**`

E ao executar, a criaturinha dá um belo Segmentation Fault. O problema é tratar como referência algo que já é um vetor.

Mas, particularmente, acredito que você deveria implodir esse código e fazer algo diferente. Vou listar o que vejo de problemático no seu código:

- Variáveis globais. Como imagino que você seja iniciante, serei mais absoluto: não use variáveis globais. Fuja delas como demônios fogem do Van Helsing.
- Constantes mágicas. Por exemplo, o que seria esse `3.5` nesta linha : `Taxa_Band_Tar[i] = x*3.5;`? Qual o "sentido da vida" desse valor? E dos outros valores? Constantes mágicas desse gênero devem ser nomeadas e, se possível, colocadas em um *header file*.
- Funções com parâmetros demais. Para que tanto parâmetro numa mesma função? Pelo que notei, estes parâmetros são de alguma forma relacionados, como se fossem atributos de algum objeto no mundo real - a saber, uma conta de luz.
- Pouca encapsulação - parte do problema apontado acima: os parâmetros das funções deveriam estar "mais próximos", formando uma unidade lógica - como uma `struct`.

Comment: `scanf()`, tudo bem, mas `printf()` é ótimo (embora tenha espaço para melhorias; vide os métodos `string.Format()` de vários descendentes de C)

Comment: É, eu fui meio radical com `printf ()`. É que ele é mal utilizado - o pessoal usando `%d` para imprimir `float`. É fácil abusar dele